# How to get my function to take higher values

Tags: r, digit

In R I have writing this function

```
ifun = function(m)  {
o=c()
for(k in 1:m) {
o[k]= prod(1:k)/ prod(2*(1:k)+1  )
}
o_sum=2*(1+sum(o)) # Final result   
print(o_sum)
}
```

I want the values for `ifun()` for high values. For example

```
 sprintf("%.100f",ifun(170) )
```

gives this output:

```
[1] 3.141593
[1] "3.1415926535897931159979634685441851615905761718750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

But when I take higher values it can give me any value. For example

```
sprintf("%.100f",ifun(180) )
```

gives me this output

```
[1] NaN
[1] "NaN"
```

How can I rewrite me code so I can take `ifun` for larger values?
Also, I use this function to approximate pi but for

```
> ifun(x>50)
```

it gives me the same result over and over again and don't make my approximation any better.

---

### EDIT

I tried to use the method on Macin series as well I wrote this in R

```
mac = function(m, approx=TRUE){   
o1 = as.bigq(NULL)   
o2 = as.bigq(NULL)
for(k in 1:m) {
k <- as.bigq(k)
     o1 = c(o1, 1/((2*k+1)*5^(2*k+1))  *(-1)^k)
     o2 = c(o2, 1/((2*k+1)*239^(2*k+1))  *(-1)^k)

   }   
  o_sum = 16*(1/5+sum(o1)) -4*(1/239+sum(o2))   
  if(approx){
     as.numeric(o_sum)   
  } else{
     o_sum   } }

 library(Rmpfr)  x <- mac(250, approx=FALSE)  mpfr(x,256)
```

This gives me a strange output namely

```
> 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits  [1]
> 3.1415926535897934 18913264129286527160857809883357101405
```

It only gives me the first 16 correct digits, it can't give me more.
What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gmp`. It can give the exact result as a rational number if you want.

```
library(gmp)

ifun = function(m, approx=TRUE){
  o = as.bigq(NULL)
  for(k in 1:m) {
    r <- as.bigz(1:k)
    o = c(o, prod(r)/ prod(2*r+1 ))
  }
  o_sum = 2*(1+sum(o)) 
  if(approx){
    as.numeric(o_sum)
  }else{
    o_sum
  }
}
```

---

```
> ifun(4, approx=FALSE)
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 976/315
> ifun(180)
[1] 3.141593
```

---

### Edit

Actually to convert the exact rational number to a decimal number, it is better to use the `Rmpfr` library:

```
> library(Rmpfr)
> x <- ifun(250, approx=FALSE)
> mpfr(x,256)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
[1] 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628613
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. ifun(x) appriximate pi well but for x larger than 50 I simply get the same value over and over again, namely: > sprintf("%.50f",  ifun(500))
[1] "3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500"

Comment: @OlePetersen Perhaps a better approximation is not possible ?

Comment: This is pretty amazing!! Thanks!

Comment: @OlePetersen I think your code evaluates `1/((2*k+1)*5^(2*k+1))*(-1)^k` with `k` a classical integer, and then converts the result to `bigq`. Try to add `k <- as.bigz(k)` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: No sorry that does not work. Do `k <- as.bigq(k)` instead.

Comment: Also replace `o_sum` with `16*(1/as.bigz(5)+sum(o1)) - 4*(sum(o2)+1/as.bigz(239))`. Otherwise `1/239` is not evaluated as an exact rational. I've checked and the result is correct up to 50 digits now (at least).

Comment: @OlePetersen Nice. BTW you might be interested in [this blog article](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/hypergeometric.html).

Comment: If one want to have more digits printet, say 5,000 digits, I need to increase x, the number of bits or what can be done?